# How to use Laravel Mix if I have 3rd party plugins?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mix

I know that we can add CSS & JS files in public folder or our application and then use them in our views with `<link>` and `<script>` tags. But I'm having difficulty in understand the concept, that if I have Custom CSS/JS files. And then some 3rd party plugins I'm using as well. How will I use  **Laravel Mix**  then? For now I understand that we can do SCSS/LESS styling using Laravel Mix Webpack, but how this will happen in this scenario.

Comment: what scenario are you talking about?

Comment: The scenario where I have  a few CSS files let's say from Bootstrap, Owl-Carousel etc etc,, and Then some JS files like Jquery, Bootstrap's js, and Owl-carousel's js files.

Comment: what do you want to do with the css and the js?

Comment: I want them to compile/minify them using webpack provided by Laravel mix.

Comment: and what's the problem?you don't know how? or what?

Comment: I am not sure how will I add those files and where would I put them. In public folder or assets?

Comment: you put them in the css /js folders of your public path, doesn't matter the path

Comment: So where does laravel mix comes in?

Comment: when you want to minify, join the files, did you read the laravel documentation?

Comment: yeah I have. I'm not sure what to do next after laravel.mix.